# Is it possible to design an algorithm that is based on the xor of the plaintext bits?

Tags: encryption, public-key, functional-encryption

Let E be some IND-CPA public key encryption scheme. Given two users with public keys $pk_0,pk_1$ respectively, each user $i$ selects a nonce $r_i$ at random and computes an encryption $c_i = E_{pk_i,r_i}(b_i)$ of some secret bit $b_i\in\{0,1\}$ selected by the user. Is it possible to construct an algorithm A such that

$
  \begin{array}{ c l }
    A(c_1,c_2)= 
\begin{cases}
    (E_{pk_0,r'}(0),E_{pk_1,r''}(1)) & \text{if } b_0 \oplus b_1 = 1\\
     (E_{pk_0,r'}(1),E_{pk_1,r''}(0)),              & \text{if } b_0 \oplus b_1 = 0
\end{cases}
  \end{array}
$
where r' and r'' are random nonces that might be chosen by A, by the users (r' is chosen by user 0 and r'' is chosen by user 1), or it can be a result of some computation of A.
This should be without the knowledge of the secret keys associated with $pk_0,pk_1$ (in particular, A is not a constructed based on the knowledge of the secret keys of the users)?

Comment: Does $f$ know the $b$ values?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Good comment, I tried to simplify things, but perhaps it makes it less understandable. $b_0$ and $b_1$ are not input of A,but only the encryptions of them are inputs. The more elaborative setting is that there are two users with public keys $pk_0$ and $pk_1$ who encrypt these bits. E is in fact IND-CPA. I tagged it as homomorphic because I thought that the encryption scheme need to satisfy some homomorphic property. I will edit the question so that it will be more understandable.

Comment: Anyway, I had some thought on that and it seems that it may actually be trivial. The algorithm simply selects a bit, encrypt it, and set it as the first argument of the algorithm. The it checks if the first ciphertext of result is an encryption of 0 or 1.  This will reveal the other user's bit because of the xor. Then, A can do it to the other user and reveal the other user's bit. Then it can compute the desired function.

Comment: I've removed the homomorphic encryption tag for now, as it may wrong-foot people.

Comment: This seems to depend on whether A can find r such that the encryption of 0 and 1 collide using r as randomness. Such r would give a decryption failure in step 4 of fgrieu's answer.

Comment: @erth : for what you describe to happen, $A$ would need to be able to craft $r''_0$ and $r''_1$ (possibly equal) such that $E_{pk',r''_1}(1)=E_{pk',r''_0}(0)$, _without knowledge of the matching $sk'$_. It would thus be possible to turn $A$ into a method allowing anyone to ambiguously encrypt per $E$; pretty strange public key encryption scheme! Another way to look at it is that if decryption fails at my step 4, then the desired property for $A$ just does not hold.

Comment: @fgrieu yes, I agree. This seems to be a theoretical exercise so I'm just noting that we're using IND-CPA security, which says something about the security of an honestly generated ciphertext, to prove something about adversarially generated ciphertexts.

Answer (score 1):

If I get the question correctly, what's asked is impossible.

Argument: Assume $A$ exists. We'll use it, and the three algorithms of the public key encryption scheme, in order to tell if a cryptogram $c=E_{pk,r}(x)$ is for $x=0$ or $x=1$, in an experiment where we are given $pk$ and $c$ (but not the private key $sk$ matching $pk$, nor $x$). This contradicts the given that $E$ is IND-CPA, hence the assumption does not hold.

We compute $x$ in 4 steps:

1. We use the key generation algorithm to build one known $(pk',sk')$ pair.
2. We use the encryption algorithm to compute $c'=E_{pk',\hat r}(0)$ for some $\hat r$ that we select arbitrarily within the constraints set by the encryption algorithm.
3. We compute $A(c,c')$ using $A$ (giving it $pk$ and $pk'$ as auxiliary input, replacing $pk_0$ and $pk_1$ if $A$ needs such input; we know $pk$ because that's a given, and we know $pk'$ from step 1). $A$ outputs a pair $(d,d')$. We extract $d'$.
4. We use the decryption algorithm to decipher $d'$ per private key $sk'$ that we know from step 1. The defining property of $A$ implies that the deciphered plaintext is the desired $x$, by examination of the two cases:

   - if $x=1$, then $x\oplus 0=1$, thus the top case applies, thus $d'$ must be $E_{pk',r''}(1)$ for some $r''$, thus $d'$ must decipher to $1$.
   - if $x=0$, then $x\oplus 0=0$, thus the bottom case applies, thus $d'$ must be $E_{pk',r''}(0)$ for some $r''$, thus $d'$ must decipher to $0$.

Comment: Thanks @fgrieu. Exactly. That also what I tried to say in my comment (I wrote trivial, though I meant that it should not be possible). You wrote it formally with much better and precise explanation.